# QListView, set maximum content height

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview

I want to use QListView to display a number of records, Set-up so far:

```
mplvRecs = new QListView(this);
mpsiModel = new QStandardItemModel(DataSets::mscuint16Rows,
                                   DataSets::mscuint16Cols, this);
```

mscuint16Rows and mscuint16Cols:

```
const quint16 DataSets::mscuint16Rows = 4;
const quint16 DataSets::mscuint16Cols = 1;
```

What I want to do is set the height of the list view to the height of exactly 4 rows, however it seems to be at least double that size.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Provide the code how you set the height.

Comment: @user1810087, I'm not currently setting the height at all, I add the list view to a QVBoxLayout.

Comment: Per default all members of QVBoxLayout are spanned to it's size which itself spans to the size of the parent (the window if the QVBoxLayot is set on it). Means, the list view is as height as the parent. Try to use [addStretch(1)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addStretch) and see if there is a difference.

Comment: @user1810087, can I enforce the size of the list view to a specific number of rows?

Comment: Kinda... you can use the size hint of the rows to calculate the height. But in my experience, it is not a perfect solution and does not work properly sometimes.